# Python - I dont understand this ID situation

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I have read documentation about `id()` this work like this

```
myvar='asd'
print id(myvar)
```

But in this code i cant understand how is it work

```
from Tkinter import *
import time
import random

class pelota:
    def __init__(self,canvas,raqueta,color):
        self.canvas=canvas
        self.raqueta=raqueta
        self.id=canvas.create_oval(10,10,25,25, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id,250,125)
        empezar=[-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4,5]
        random.shuffle(empezar)
        self.x=empezar[0]
        self.y=-3
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()

    def golpea_raqueta(self, pos):
        raqueta_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.raqueta.id)
        if pos[2] >= raqueta_pos[0] and  pos[0] <= raqueta_pos[2]:
            if pos[3] >=raqueta_pos[1] and pos[3] <= raqueta_pos[3]:
```

Im talking about this specific lines

```
 self.raqueta=raqueta


  raqueta_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.raqueta.id)
```

How id can work on (self.raqueta.id)?

**FULL CODE**

```
from Tkinter import *
import time
import random

class pelota:
    def __init__(self,canvas,raqueta,color):
        self.canvas=canvas
        self.raqueta=raqueta
        self.id=canvas.create_oval(10,10,25,25, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id,250,125)
        empezar=[-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4,5]
        random.shuffle(empezar)
        self.x=empezar[0]
        self.y=-3
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()

    def golpea_raqueta(self, pos):
        raqueta_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.raqueta.id)
        if pos[2] >= raqueta_pos[0] and  pos[0] <= raqueta_pos[2]:
            if pos[3] >=raqueta_pos[1] and pos[3] <= raqueta_pos[3]:
                return True
        return False

    def dibujar(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id,self.x,self.y)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[1]<=0:
            self.y=3
        if pos[0]<=0:
            self.x=3
        if pos[2]>= self.canvas_width :
            self.x=-3
        if self.golpea_raqueta(pos) == True:
            self.y=-3
        if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height :
            self.y=-3

class raqueta:
    def __init__(self,canvas,color):
        self.canvas=canvas
        self.id=self.canvas.create_rectangle(10,10,100,20, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id , 200,300)
        self.x = 0
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', self.izqu)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', self.dere)

    def dibujar(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id,self.x,0)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[0]<=0:
            self.x=0
        if pos[0]>0:
            self.x=0
        elif pos[2]>=self.canvas_width:
            self.x=0
    def izqu(self,evt):
        self.x=-20


    def dere(self,evt):
        self.x=20

vent= Tk()
vent.title('mipong')
vent.resizable(0,0)
vent.wm_attributes('-topmost',1)
canvas= Canvas(vent, width=500,height=500, bd=0,highlightthicknes=0)
canvas.pack()
vent.update()

raqueta= raqueta(canvas,'blue')    
pelota=pelota(canvas,raqueta,'red')


#help(Tkinter.Canvas.winfo_height)
while 1:
    pelota.dibujar()
    raqueta.dibujar()
    vent.update_idletasks()
    vent.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an item on the canvas, it returns a unique identifier. In the code you posted, you assign the identifier to `self.id`. While the name is similar to the built-in function named `id`, they are completely unrelated.

To avoid confusion, you can rename `self.id` to `self.canvas_id`

Comment: I think the same thing but... when I change the name with _id the code isn't work however i finally fix it but i dont understand that line. Another functional options was change (self.raqueta.id) to (real id number) or create var and save there  var = id(object) thank you. Can u try explain that me with the full code because i cant understand .

Comment: @Shiki: I don't know how I can make it any clearer. When you create an oval you get back an identifier. You can use that identifier later to modify that oval (or any other canvas object). It has nothng to do with the `id` function.

Comment: yes i understand that,, my problem is this... lets go for a example i create self.a= canvas.create_x >>>>with that i got the id, ok now i need call because i need work with that >>>a_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.a) <<<<this dont work for some reason BUT if I add id this self.a.id this work.  I try search the var self.raqueta.id in my code this doesn't exist... you just can find self.raqueta. Then why i must call it by self.raqueta.id or why i cant call it by self.id or just self.raqueta